# Minimizing using a Karnaugh map when given as subscripts F4,2655

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I have to minimize the expression using minterms and a Karnaugh map:

$F_{4,2655}$

How might I get this expression I am given into a form much like a typical boolean algebra minification question? I do not understand the given notation.

From a classmate they commented that the notation means the following:

> 2655 would be the sum of all
>   the minterm values of function F, expressed in decimal (which when
>   converted to binary gives the Boolean representation that corresponds
>   to truth table).

So...

$2655_{10} = 0000 1010 0101 1111_2$

Then I need to do something with this from here, but I am not sure what. I included an extra 4 bits as I believe the $2^4$ in the question represents the amount of bits. Now having this somewhat converted I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map k-map is just the shortform

Comment: But what does $F_{4,2655}$ mean?

Comment: @HenningMakholm That is exactly what I am here for. I have no idea what it means yet have to solve that.

Comment: Then I think you should reformulate your question such that that is what you actually ask -- the stuff about Karnaugh maps then seems to be more context for the real question ("the notation $F_{4,2655}$ seems to denote a particular truth function, but which?") than an actual pat of the question.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I would be more than happy to clarify that in the question, however where exactly needs altering? My last sentence states what I am looking for.

Comment: Your last sentence reads: "I know how to use a Karnaugh map, just normally I am given a boolean expression to use which I could make into a K-map, however I am confused how I create a K-map from the type of form I was given in this question." That says nothing about the $F_{4,2655}$ notation, but reads _exactly_ like you already know what $F_{4,2655}$ is and expect that the reader will know that too. If you want to ask what $F_{4,2655}$ might mean, **actually ask that** instead of muddling the water by talking about what you're going to do with the function once you figure out which it is.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have altered the question.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I also added some dialogue from a classmate on what the notation likely means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that **F4,2655** is a shorthand notation for the Boolean expression with four inputs which has a truthtable with the binary equivalent of 2655 as output column.

The truthtable looks as follows:

```
A B C D F    
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
0 1 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 1
1 0 1 0 0
1 0 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 1
1 1 0 1 1 
1 1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

Translated into a Karnaugh map

```
             AB
       00  01  11  10
      +---+---+---+---+
   00 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
      +---+---+---+---+
   01 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
CD    +---+---+---+---+
   11 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
   10 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
      +---+---+---+---+
```

Resulting minimized expression:

```
A & D  +  B & !D
```

---

Reversing the order of bits in the output column results in:

Truthtable:

```
A B C D  F
0 0 0 0  1
0 0 0 1  1
0 0 1 0  1
0 0 1 1  1
0 1 0 0  1
0 1 0 1  0
0 1 1 0  1
0 1 1 1  0
1 0 0 0  0
1 0 0 1  1
1 0 1 0  0
1 0 1 1  1
1 1 0 0  0
1 1 0 1  0 
1 1 1 0  0
1 1 1 1  0
```

Karnaugh map:

```
             AB
       00  01  11  10
      +---+---+---+---+
   00 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
      +---+---+---+---+
   01 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
CD    +---+---+---+---+
   11 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
   10 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
      +---+---+---+---+
```

Minimized expression:

```
!B & D + !A & !D
```

So, both cases yield a somewhat similar expression

Comment: I think your answer is incorrect. I believe the extra zero's from the 16 bit number should end up on the bottom and you have it the other way around.

Comment: Yes, that might be. It is a matter of convention, if you are looking on the output column from the left or from the right. The general approach should be ok.